# call to onNewIntent() in Fragment activity using google maps api v2

Tags: android-intent

when i make an intent of FragmentActivity, in an activity then it goes to onCreate() method of FragmentActivity in stead of going onNewIntent().why..??

here is my code..

```
    intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("geopoints", pointsExtra);

    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("dateList", dateList);
    this.startActivity(intent);
```

where FirstActivity is the class whose onNewIntent() method i want to call..

plz help me...sorry for my english.:)